# Why is 'taxonomy_term' missing?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm not able to retrieve the `taxonomy_term` on a certain server.

```
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
```

After this call, `$term` is NULL.

I have read about the different ways of getting the value in [various comments](https://api.drupal.org/comment/50598#comment-50598), but none of those techniques work for me either.

The Taxonomy module is enabled.

**Edit:** This is in an AJAX call.  (`current_path()` is `system/ajax`.)  Which probably means I'm *not* on a taxonomy term page..?

Comment: Where are you using that code (and in what context)?

Comment: @Clive: this is in a custom `commerce_cart_order_id` hook.  A nearby comment says, "If this is the Affiliates cart, fetch the term and return the cart order id that has the property `$order->data['affiliates'][tid]` set to `TRUE`."

Comment: That'll be the problem - `menu_get_object()` loads an entity related to the current menu path - so if you're on taxonomy/term/10 for example, your current code would work. To load a term from its ID you can use `taxonomy_term_load()` if that helps

Comment: @Clive: I believe I want the former.  The `tid` property is the key we use to find the correct order.  I guess I'm confused in any case why `taxonomy_term_load(6)` returns a valid object (it does!), while `menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', n)` returns NULL for various *n*?

Comment: Because the 2nd arg to `menu_get_object()` doesn't take a term ID, it's: _"The position of the object in the path, where the first path segment is 0. For node/%node, the position of %node is 1, but for comment/reply/%node, it's 2. Defaults to 1."_. It only make sense to use it if you're actually on a taxonomy term page, in which case the only valid argument is 2 (unless you're overriding the entity URI for taxonomy_term somewhere, but you'd probably know about that), 2 being the position at which you can find the term ID in the router path `taxonomy/term/%`

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing as Clive did. What you are trying to do makes no sense, which you will see if you read the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

Comment: I'm trying to *retrieve* the term id so that I can use it to look up an order..?  (As shown in the comments of those docs!)

Comment: Just so I understand, you've confirmed that your implementation of `hook_commerce_order_id()` is being invoked on the taxonomy term page that you're testing (that has a path of taxonomy/term/6), but when the hook is invoked on that page, `menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2)` doesn't provide you with a valid term object?

Comment: @Clive: just made an edit that might be more relevant than I thought earlier, heh.  This is in an AJAX call, if that helps, but otherwise I think you have it.

Comment: Yep you're edit has it, the path for an AJAX call isn't the same as the referrer so `menu_get_object()` is out. Making an assumption that you're making alterations to `#ajax` properties in `hook_form_alter()`, that would be place the to stash the term. So `$form['#mymodule_tid'] = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2)->tid;`, and then in the ajax callback you can use `$term = taxonomy_term_load($form['#mymodule_tid']);`. If you're using a non-form ajax method we'll need to know what that is to advise

Comment: I get it, and your suggestions make sense.  Storing the TID in the form should be viable.  Thanks so much for your patience (again) -- if you care to make an answer, I'll be happy to mark it!